# Undefined method 'title' when using <% page "New user" %>

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When using the tag

```
<% title "New user" %>
```

in my Rails 2.3.2 views I get an undefined method 'title' error. Can anyone shed some light?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ignore me. I forgot to add the title helper :$ I blame Monday morning.

Comment: They're part of Ryan Bates' nifty generators. You can get them from the GitHub repo (git://github.com/ryanb/nifty-generators.git). Specific method is in this file (http://github.com/ryanb/nifty-generators/blob/master/rails_generators/nifty_layout/templates/helper.rb). Hope this helps :)